# Android Pokemon go - General vs miscellaneous notifications?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

Does anyone know the difference between general and miscellaneous app notifications on Android? I'm assuming general is like for regular reminders for raids and miscellaneous is like event reminders or something?

Answer (score 2):

The General category includes items like announcements, reminders, etc.  I practically ignore this category, so I do not recall the complete list; feel free to edit and add to this.

The Miscellaneous category includes items like egg hatches, buddy finding candy, and weekly Adventure Sync rewards.  I do monitor this category since I like to know when an egg hatches.